# Requisição Assíncrona Jquery+Ajax+PHP retorna objeto vazio

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Preciso verificar se o cnpj já está cadastrado no banco de dados e retornar para o cliente se o mesmo já existe no banco de dados, o problema que eu não quero que aconteça o refresh da página para que o usuário não perca os dados digitados, o script php está funcionando perfeitamente, o scripth js também mas só com a instrução async:false, quando tiro o async: false ele simplesmente não retorna nada.

Script JS:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#btn_salva_cliente').click(function(){

            if($('#cnpj_cliente').val().length > 0){

                $.ajax({

                    url:'assets/scripts/php/registra_cliente.php',

                    type:'POST',

                    async: false,

                    data:$('#form_cliente').serialize(),

                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }


                });



            }


        });


    });
```

SCRIPT PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
        header('Location: index.php?erro=1');
}

//inclue a classe db no script atual
require_once('db.class.php');

//recuperando os dados do formulario de 
//cadastro de Clientes via Método POST        
//e atribuindo a uma variável
$cnpj_cliente = $_POST['cnpj_cliente'];
$nome_razao_cliente = $_POST['nome_razao_cliente'];
$inscricao_cliente = $_POST['inscricao_cliente'];
$identificacao_icms = $_POST['identificacao_icms'];
$cep = $_POST['cep'];
$rua_cliente = $_POST['rua_cliente'];
$numero_endereco_cliente = $_POST['numero_endereco_cliente'];
$complemento_endereco_cliente = $_POST['complemento_endereco_cliente'];
$bairro_cliente = $_POST['bairro_cliente'];
$uf_cliente = $_POST['uf_cliente'];
$cidade_cliente = $_POST['cidade_cliente'];
$pais_cliente = $_POST['pais_cliente'];
$email_cliente = $_POST['email_cliente'];
$telefone_cliente = $_POST['telefone_cliente'];
$observacao_cliente = $_POST['observacao_cliente'];

//instancia um objeto da classe db
$objDb = new db();

//instancia um objeto que recebe a função
//que faz a conexão com o banco de dados
$link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();

//variável utilizada para verificar se
//o usuário e o email já existe
$cnpj_existe = false;

$imprime = '';
//verificar se o cnpj já existe            

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj_cliente' ";

if($resultado_id = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

    $dados_cliente = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id);

    if(isset($dados_cliente['cnpj'])){
        $cnpj_existe = true;
    }

}else{
        echo 'Erro ao tentar localizar o registro de cnpj';
    }

if($cnpj_existe){        
             echo 'CNPJ já CADASTRADO';   

             die();
}    

$sql1 = " INSERT INTO clientes(cnpj, razao_social, inscricao_estadual, id_inscricao_estadual, cep, rua,";
$sql1 .= " numero_endereco, complemento, bairro, uf, cidade, pais, email, telefone, observacoes) ";
$sql1 .= " VALUES ('$cnpj_cliente', '$nome_razao_cliente', '$inscricao_cliente', '$identificacao_icms',";
$sql1 .= " '$cep', '$rua_cliente', '$numero_endereco_cliente', '$complemento_endereco_cliente',";
$sql1 .= " '$bairro_cliente', '$uf_cliente', '$cidade_cliente', '$pais_cliente', '$email_cliente', ";
$sql1 .= " '$telefone_cliente', '$observacao_cliente' )";

//executa query
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql1)){            
        echo 'Parabéns CLIENTE CADASTRADO!! ';     
}else{                   
        echo 'ERRO AO CADASTRAR CLIENTE!!';           
}


?>
```

Script db.class.php

```
<?php

//classe para conexão ao banco  de dados

class db{

    //host de hospedagem do banco de dados
    private $host = 'xxxx';

    //usuario de acesso ao banco de dados
    private $usuario = 'xxxx';      

    //senha do usuario do banco de dados
    private $senha = 'xxxx';

    //nome do banco de dados
    private $database = 'xxxx';

    public function conecta_mysql(){
    //função  que faz a conexão com o banco de dados propriamente dita    
        //criar conexao
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->database);

        //ajusta o charset do banco de dados com a aplicação
        mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');


        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        //condição que verifica erro de conexao de bd    
            echo'Erro ao tentar se conectar com o BD MySQL:'.mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        return $con;

    }
}


?>
```

Ta tudo funcionando, apenas não consigo pegar o retorno fazendo a requisição sem dar o refresh. 
Quando uso complete em vez de success ele retorna assim: object Object
Alguém pode me dar uma opnião de como  fazer isso?

Comment: Poste o código da classe db

Comment: Feito, inclui a classe db.

Comment: Era apenas o button, estava como submit, troquei para button funcionou, dica do Darlan! Obrigado!!